# call a fragmnet inside its ListView Adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a `Fragment` which has a `ListView` inside it , in each row of my `ListView` i have a delete `Button` which works perfectly, what i need is to refresh my `ListView` to show the updated data.
my question is how can i refresh my `ListView` inside its `Adapter`.
this is my Adapter:

```
public class BrowserBannedListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context mContext;
private static List<BrowserBannedSites> listUrlForAdapter;
AppSQLiteHelper db;




public BrowserBannedListViewAdapter(Context c, List<BrowserBannedSites> urls) {
    mContext = c;
    listUrlForAdapter = urls;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listUrlForAdapter.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    ImageView icon;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.row_fragment_browser_url, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_fragment_browser_url_name);
        viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_fragment_browser_delete);

        viewHolder.icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                        db=new AppSQLiteHelper(mContext);

                int tempID =listUrlForAdapter.get(position).get_Id();
                db.deleteBannedSites(tempID);
  //******************** here is where i want to refresh my listview

            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
      viewHolder.text.setText(listUrlForAdapter.get(position).get_browserBannedSitesAddress());

    return convertView;
}

}
```

Comment: Did you try notifydatasetchanged() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only deleting from database will not working. you need to delete from List too.

```
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v){

      .........
      listUrlForAdapter.remove(position); // position is the position of the custom view in the list 
      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

change first the List of your data and 
You can directly call notifyDataSetChanged();

```
   @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    db=new AppSQLiteHelper(mContext);

            int tempID =listUrlForAdapter.get(position).get_Id();
            db.deleteBannedSites(tempID);
     //******************** here is where i want to refresh my listview
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh listview with notifyDataSetChanged(); but before that change (add/remove/edit) your list elements

Answer (score 0):

After delete from database first remove item from adapter also and then call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of adapter as

```
db.deleteBannedSites(tempID);
listUrlForAdapter.remove(position); // remove from adapter
notifyDataSetChanged(); //add here
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to remove the item from List in your fragment and call notifiydataSetchaned() from your fragment afterwards,

U can easily achieve this by making a public method in your fragment

```
public removeItem(Int id){
    //Remove item from the List or the DataSource Here
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

u can call this method directly from your fragment by referencing the context, just replace your

```
db.deleteBannedSites(tempID);
```

by

```
((YourFragmentClass)context).removeItem(tempID);
```